# Scons Install Builder with hard link support

Tags: scons

I am using Scons for building an environment which include propagating a partial directory structure including hard links.

So it looks like this, I compile some sources into $BIN directory, some of the created targets are hard links, and in some other module I am scanning the $BIN directory and triggering a builder which either strip the the binaries to the new target, but maintain hard links. So if there are two files which are hard links in source, it copies the first and create hard link to the other target for the second.

Now the problem is if I try to run this with -j4 for example, a race condition could happen, because at the moment the builder tries to create a hard link, the target which is created by strip is not done yet.

Below is my builder:

```
def GenerateM3Strip(target, source, env):                                      
    if type(source) is list:                                                   
        source = source[0]                                                     

    if type(target) is list:                                                   
        target = target[0]                                                     

    src_stat = os.stat(source.abspath)                                         
    if (src_stat.st_nlink > 1                                                  
            and src_stat.st_ino in GenerateM3Strip.inodes_dict):               
        previous_target = GenerateM3Strip.inodes_dict[src_stat.st_ino]         
        if target.get_dir().get_path() in previous_target:                     
            source = previous_target[target.get_dir().get_path()]              
            print('LinkTarget: %s %s' % (source.get_path(), target.get_path()))
            try:                                                               
                os.unlink(target.get_path())                                   
            except Exception:                                                  
                pass                                                           
            os.link(source.get_path(), target.get_path())                      
            return                                                             

    # We have to keep a dictionary of target directory and target pairs, to    
    # support separate hard links for different directory targets, for example:
    # fsdata/default and fsdata/bench                                          
    GenerateM3Strip.inodes_dict[src_stat.st_ino] = {                           
        target.get_dir().get_path(): target}                                   
    action_str = env.subst(cross + 'strip -o $TARGET $SOURCE',                 
                           source=source, target=target)                       
    env.Execute(env.Action(action_str))                                        


GenerateM3Strip.inodes_dict = {}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should make the hardlink target a SideEffect() with the normal target and source. Then your strip builder should make the source the target and the target the hardlink target.  That may work.

Comment: This indirectly helped me, I did not totally get what you mean, but when I looked at side effects I realized that I can avoid parallelism of the Builder by using SideEffect. But that also lead me to a bug in my builder. I always replace the value of GenerateM3Strip.inodes_dict[src_stat.st_ino] with a new dictionary instead of appending to it. For example when I have different target directories. !
But I still did not get the second part of your statement.

Comment: Assuming you have two builders: 1) creates target and hardlinks into some dir (use sideffect here for hardlink target), 2) builder which strips target and replaces hardlink.    Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes clear enough. Thanks.